# cast the native pointer to managed object

Tags: c++, c++-cli, native

I need to convert unmanaged pointer to the managed object.
Below is the code

**Wrapper.cpp**

```
 _declspec(dllexport) int UnmanagedAlgebraComputation::SubtractMultiplyWrapper(UnmanagedSubtraction *unmanagedSubtraction)
{
     AlgebraCSharp::AlgebraComputation^ obj= AlgebraCSharp::AlgebraComputation::GetObject;
     return obj->Subtraction(unmanagedSubtraction);
 }
```

Here `UnmanagedSubtraction`, `UnmanagedAlgebraComputation` is the class in my **Wrapper.h** file.

`SubtractMultiplyWrapper(UnmanagedSubtraction *unmanagedSubtraction)` is the method in my *wrapper.h* file which is implemented in my Wrapper.cpp file.

The problem is I want to pass the managed object to the  `obj->Subtraction(unmanagedSubtraction)` but `unmanagedSubtraction` is my native C pointer.

It throws the error as

> 'AlgebraCSharp::AlgebraComputation::Subtraction' : cannot convert
>   parameter 1 from 'UnmanagedSubtraction *' to
>   'AlgebraCSharp::SubtractComputation ^'

Please let me know if you have any solution related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast: You must either convert (copy the relevant contents into a managed object) or wrap (have one object be a wrapper around the other).

Comment: Thanks for the Reply.You are Right.We can't convert native pointer into managed object directly.First We have to Convert Native Pointer to IntPtr and then that IntPtr to ManagedObject.

Answer (score 1):

We cant convert Native Pointer to Managed object Directly.
First We have to convert  Native Pointer to IntPtr.
and then IntPtr to Managed object.